# Jupyter & Terminal have different Conda packages

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtual-environment

I am trying to import a module (Selenium and getting the error...

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'"
```

I am using a conda virtual environment called "py3-env'.

As you can see I have the env activated (run from Terminal)

```
(py3-env) l99333680:python s101096$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/s101096/anaconda3
                         /Users/s101096/anaconda3/envs/py3-env
base                     /anaconda3
py3-env               *  /anaconda3/envs/py3-env
```

Pwd (run from terminal)

```
(py3-env) l99333680:python s101096$ pwd
/Users/s101096/python
```

I have one kernel Spec (run from Terminal)

```
(py3-env) l99333680:python s101096$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /anaconda3/envs/py3-env/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

My Jupyter notebook server is running in the py3-env

This is the list of packages (run from Terminal) (includes Selenium)

```
(py3-env) l99333680:python s101096$ conda list
# packages in environment at /anaconda3/envs/py3-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
absl-py                   0.7.1                    py37_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astor                     0.7.1                    py37_0  
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1  
backcall                  0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
c-ares                    1.15.0               h1de35cc_1  
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0  
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0  
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1  
cryptography              2.7              py37ha12b0ac_0  
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1  
defusedxml                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    py37_0  
grpcio                    1.16.1           py37h044775b_1  
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h3134771_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
ipykernel                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            5.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0  
keras                     2.2.4                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-base                2.2.4                    py37_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libprotobuf               3.8.0                hd9629dc_0  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h27c97d8_0  
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
notebook                  5.7.8                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.16.4           py37hacdab7b_0  
numpy-base                1.16.4           py37h6575580_0  
openssl                   1.1.1c               h1de35cc_1  
pandas                    0.24.2           py37h0a44026_0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0  
plotly                    3.10.0                     py_0  
prometheus-client         0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            2.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.8.0            py37h0a44026_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pygments                  2.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0  
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.3                h359304d_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0  
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 4.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0  
retrying                  1.3.3                    py37_2  
scipy                     1.2.1            py37h1410ff5_0  
selenium                  3.141.0                  pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
sqlite                    3.28.0               ha441bb4_0  
tensorboard               1.13.1           py37haf313ee_0  
tensorflow                1.13.1          mkl_py37h70c3834_0  
tensorflow-base           1.13.1          mkl_py37h66b1bf0_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1  
terminado                 0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
tornado                   6.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0  
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
```

Now run from the Jupyter notebook...

!Conda env list

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/s101096/anaconda3
py3-env               *  /Users/s101096/anaconda3/envs/py3-env
                         /anaconda3
                         /anaconda3/envs/py3-env
```

!Pwd

```
/Users/s101096/python/scrape
```

!Jupyter kernelspec list

```
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/s101096/anaconda3/envs/py3-env/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

!Conda list

```
# packages in environment at /Users/s101096/anaconda3/envs/py3-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0  
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0  
decorator                 4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            5.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 5.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
notebook                  5.7.8                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.16.4                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1c               h1de35cc_1  
pandas                    0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0  
prometheus-client         0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            2.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.3                h359304d_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     18.0.1                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 4.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
send2trash                1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0  
six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.28.0               ha441bb4_0  
terminado                 0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
tornado                   6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
```

I get a different package list with no Selenium?

Why is this happening?

Comment: You appear to have installed the Jupyter Notebook package with PyPI. You should not use PyPI (pip) unless absolutely necessary. In this case, I think the best course of action is to create a new environment and install everything you need using `conda` (not `pip`).

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will give that a try

Comment: PS: How could you tell I used PyPi please?

Comment: The farthest right column says `pypi`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is from @darthbith's comment...

"best course of action is to create a new environment and install everything you need using conda (not pip)."